# IHaskell Kernel shutting down with ghc installed using Stack

Tags: haskell-stack, ihaskell

I managed to install IHaskell as a Jupyter Kernel, but when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
ihaskell: 
Ran commands: 
ghc-pkg check
which ghc-pkg
```

> Exception: user error (shelly did not find ghc-pkg in the PATH

which is perhaps to be expected since I don't have a global ghc install, but only through stack.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Not sure about the edit. The whole bit is an error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this error by running jupyter itself through stack:

```
 stack exec ipython -- notebook
```

It is described in [ihaskell repo](https://github.com/gibiansky/IHaskell#run-ihaskell) and linked [guide for Ubuntu 14.04](https://remusao.github.io/install-ihaskell-on-ubuntu-1404-with-stack.html).
Both Python and Haskell kernels work this way.